# Python request to authorize app api made via tyk gateway

Tags: python, python-requests, tyk

I'm working on a **python script (2.7.x) that tries to connect to a third party api via tyk gateway**. The end **api expects an auth token** in the request header and **tyk also requires its own auth token** to be present in the request header.

Now the problem that I'm facing is:

**When I try to make a request to the third party app via tyk, app is not recognising the auth token passed in the header.** 
From debugging I was able to figure out that tyk is not passing the authentication header to the app.

I'm using following piece of code to make the request

```
request.post("https://myurl.com", 
   data={"data": data_a},
   headers={"Authorization": "Basic <TYK_TOKEN>, Bearer <APP_TOKEN> })
```

Things I have tried:

- Tried passing the app token first and tyk token second, then the request won't pass tyk authorization.
- Tried passing app token alone in the request, then the request won't pass tyk authorization.
- Tried passing app token under 'Application-Authorization' header and tyk token under 'Authorization' header, then the request won't pass app authorization.

Please advise a solution.

Thanks

in advance

Answer (score 0):

Leonid from Tyk here.

So basically your upstream is protected by auth token, and your own API protected by token as well.

If your 3-rd party API have a static api key, you can just embed it to all requests as a global header:
[image]

If you have a dynamic 3-rd party key, which varies for different users, you can embed it to Key metadata, for example, "upstream_api_key" field, and add global header with dynamic value: "$tyk_meta.upstream_api_key".
[image]

If your user needs to pass this token, and you need forward it to upstream, Tyk and Upstream authentification should happen in different HTTP headers.

Hope it helps!